# Emacs -- test for same buffer in other windows with different width

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am looking for some assistance, please, to test for the existence of the same buffer in more than one window (on any frame) **and** whether the `window-width` of those windows (containing that particular buffer) are different.

---

- Example I

**Frame # 1**:

Window A -- `minor-mode-xyz` -- `(= (window-width) 55)` -- `(equal (buffer-name) "*TEST*")`

Window B -- nothing important to this example

Window C -- `minor-mode-xyz` -- `(= (window-width) 55)` -- `(equal (buffer-name) "*TEST*")`

**Frame # 2**:

Window A -- `minor-mode-xyz` -- `(= (window-width) 100)` -- `(equal (buffer-name) "*TEST*")`

Window B -- nothing important to this example

Window C -- `minor-mode-xyz` -- `(= (window-width) 55)` -- `(equal (buffer-name) "*TEST*")`

Result:  `(message "The test yielded a positive result -- do something now.")`

---

- Example II

**Frame # 1**:

Window A -- `minor-mode-xyz` -- `(= (window-width) 100)` -- `(equal (buffer-name) "*TEST*")`

Window B -- nothing important to this example

Window C -- `minor-mode-xyz` -- `(= (window-width) 100)` -- `(equal (buffer-name) "*TEST*")`

**Frame # 2**:

Window A -- `minor-mode-xyz` -- `(= (window-width) 100)` -- `(equal (buffer-name) "*TEST*")`

Window B -- nothing important to this example

Window C -- `minor-mode-xyz` -- `(= (window-width) 100)` -- `(equal (buffer-name) "*TEST*")`

Result:  `(message "Everything is PERFECT -- do not do anything !!!")`

---

- Example III

**Frame # 1**:

Window A -- `minor-mode-xyz` -- `(= (window-width) 100)` -- `(equal (buffer-name) "*TEST*")`

Window B -- nothing important to this example

Window C -- nothing important to this example

**Frame # 2**:

Window A -- nothing important to this example

Window B -- nothing important to this example

Window C -- nothing important to this example

Result:  `(message "Everything is PERFECT -- do not do anything !!!")`

---

Here is an example where the `window-width` in both windows is exactly equal, and the minor mode works well.

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [lawlist.com](http://www.lawlist.com/images/example_06_16_2014_a.png))</sub>

---

Here is an example where the `window-width` in the windows are *not* equal, and the minor mode goes haywire in any window that does not have focus -- e.g., the horizontal / vertical yellow lines are not drawn correctly.  When a situation like this arises, the best way to handle it would probably be to have a test and when it returns positive, disable the yellow horizontal / vertical lines in all windows.

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [lawlist.com](http://www.lawlist.com/images/example_06_16_2014_b.png))</sub>

---

The following is just a draft concept idea, but is not yet capable of handling the test that is needed:

```lisp
(defun test-function (&optional all-frames)
"If the same buffer displays on any frame -- with different `window-width`,
then do something."
  (let* (
      (wins (window-list (selected-frame) 'no-minibuf))
      (bufs (delete-dups (mapcar #'window-buffer wins))))
    (dolist (buf bufs)
      (with-current-buffer buf
        (dolist (win
            (get-buffer-window-list (current-buffer) 'no-minibuf all-frames))
          (select-window win)
          (when test-mode
            (message "hello-world.")))))))
```

Comment: Clarifying question: do you want to test for the existence of a *specific* buffer (say, the current buffer), or for *any* buffer that is duplicated across windows?

Comment: @Dan -- The most likely situation will be the `current-buffer` -- e.g., killing an *unrelated* buffer may reveal a new `current-buffer` that is already displayed somewhere else; `split-window-horizontally` will naturally display the `current-buffer`; and switching to a buffer might also be one that is displayed elsewhere.  When using `display-buffer`, however, there might be a situation where it is not the `current-buffer` (since that new target window might not necessarily be selected).  So, the all inclusive test, should cover all scenarios please -- i.e., *any* buffer with `minor-mode-xyz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that returns a list of pairs of windows that share the same buffer but have different width:

```lisp
(defun window-pairs ()
  (let (wmap ret)
    ;; get a list of all windows
    (dolist (frame (frame-list))
      (dolist (window (window-list frame))
        (let* ((buffer (window-buffer window))
               (assoc (assoc buffer wmap)))
          ;; if the window shares the window with some previously
          ;; visited windows, also compare their widths
          (if assoc
              (let ((other-windows (cdr assoc)))
                (dolist (other-window other-windows)
                  (unless (= (window-width window) (window-width other-window))
                    (push (cons window other-window) ret)))
                (push (cons buffer (cons window other-windows)) wmap))
            (push (cons buffer (list window)) wmap)))))
    ret))
```

It finds all windows that share the same buffer, and each time a new window is found whose buffer has been seen before, it iterates over the previous windows to compare their widths with that of the current window.